# How do I invoke a private static method using reflection (Java)?

Tags: java, reflection, invoke

I would like to invoke a private static method. I have its name. I've heard it can be done using Java reflection mechanism. How can I do it?

**EDIT:** One problem I encountered when trying to invoke the method is how to specify the type of its argument. My method receives one argument and its type is Map. Therefore I cannot do `Map<User, String>.TYPE` (In run time there's no such a thing as Map because of Java Type erasure). Is there another way to get the method?

Comment: try `MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("myMethod", Map.class);` for your case

Comment: Funnily enough the generic information of the method still is available at runtime. `Method.getGenericParameterTypes`

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Let's say you want to call MyClass.myMethod(int x);

```
Method m = MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("myMethod", Integer.TYPE);
m.setAccessible(true); //if security settings allow this
Object o = m.invoke(null, 23); //use null if the method is static
```

Comment: Thanks. My method receives one parameter and its type is Map<User, String>. Therefore I cannot do 'Map<User, String>.TYPE'. Is there another way to get the method?

Comment: @snakile:try `MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("myMethod", Map.class);` for your case

Comment: How you can change with (class, string, etc. ).type ?

Comment: @delive Usually you can just use `YourClass.class` as argument, the `Integer.TYPE` is just a crutch for primitive types, which have no real class.

Comment: But then how would you get the return value of the method? Since it's static it won't be saved in `o`.

Comment: @Celeritas The return value should be in `o`, this is *not* the object you're calling it on (if you had an object, it needs to be the first argument of `invoke`).

Comment: @Landei then what method do you call on `o` to get the value?

Comment: @Celeritas It *is* the value, you just need to cast it. E.g. if your static method returns a `String`, you can cast `o` to a `String`. `Method.invoke` must be able to return values from all kinds of methods, so which return type should it use in its method declaration? It can't know the type, so it uses `Object` (as some other reflection stuff does as well).

Answer (score 10):

Invoke main from [reflection tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html)

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class InvokeMain {
    public static void main(String... args) {
    try {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(args[0]);
        Class[] argTypes = new Class[] { String[].class };
        Method main = c.getDeclaredMethod("main", argTypes);
        String[] mainArgs = Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 1, args.length);
        System.out.format("invoking %s.main()%n", c.getName());
        main.invoke(null, (Object)mainArgs);

        // production code should handle these exceptions more gracefully
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't say `Map<K,V>.class`. This is because of *type erasure*. At runtime, there's no such thing.

Luckily, you *can* say just plain old `Map.class`. It's all the same at runtime.

If the warnings bother you, search for other questions related to generics and type erasure, there's a wealth of information on the subject here.

Answer (score 1):

I use a single method that encapsulates getting the target method and then invoking it.  Probably has some limitations, of course.  Here is the method put into a class and its JUnit test:

```
public class Invoker {
/**
 * Get method and invoke it.
 * 
 * @author jbetancourt
 * 
 * @param name of method
 * @param obj Object to invoke the method on
 * @param types parameter types of method
 * @param args to method invocation
 * @return return value
 * @throws Exception for unforseen stuff
 */
public static final <T> Object invokeMethod(final String name, final T obj,
  final Class<?>[] types, final Object... args) throws Exception {

    Method method = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(name, types);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    return method.invoke(obj, args);
}

/**
 * Embedded JUnit tests.
 */
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public static class InvokerTest {
    /** */
    @Test
    public void testInvoke() throws Exception {
        class TestTarget {
            private String hello() {
                return "Hello world!";
            }
        }

        String actual = (String) Invoker.invokeMethod("hello",
                new TestTarget(), new Class<?>[] {});
        String expected = "Hello world!";
        assertThat(actual, is(expected));

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
Object insecure; //This needs to be an initialized reference

Class c = insecure.getClass();
Method m = c.getMethod(name, parameterTypes); //Fill the name and types in
m.setAccessible(true);
m.invoke( insecure, parameters ); //Fill in the parameters you would like
```

There are a number of checked exceptions which may be thrown.  Both parameterTypes and parameters are ellipse arguments (variable length), fill them in as needed.  The JVM by specification has a strongly typed calling convention so you need to know the parameter types.

With that said, unless you are writing some sort of application container, server component container, RMI-like system, or JVM based langauge you should avoid doing this.