# Using reflection to call static method for return value

Tags: java, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I invoke a private static method using reflection (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770425/how-do-i-invoke-a-private-static-method-using-reflection-java)

So there is a method named something along the lines of "getInstance" which just returns an instance of a certain class. It's a static method with no arguments.

How could I call that method, and get the return value (the instance) of the class? Every method I try to use requires me to have an instance of the class in the arguments it seems.

For example, I try to use

```
Method method = classLoader.loadClass("testClass").getMethod("getInstance", null);
            Object object = method.invoke(null, null);
```

but I always get a null pointer exception at this line,

```
Object object = method.invoke(null, null);
```

Which I'm assuming I get since the object it asks for is null.

Thanks for any help.

Edit: Method is not null. I am doing a `System.out.println(method == null);` and it prints out false.

Comment: Have you read javadoc API http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object...)

Comment: @gigadot Yes, it says that the first argument in invoke can be null if it's a static method. `If the underlying method is static, then the specified obj argument is ignored. It may be null.`

Comment: And you're sure that `method` is a non-null value?

Comment: @zeller Yes, I've done a System.out.println(method == null); and it prints out false

Comment: Give us the stacktrace of the NullPointerException. If it ends at that line (and not in the call to invoke), then method must be null, as it is the only thing deferenced on that line.

Comment: Did you check if you are really entering into that method? I assume you just have one method with that name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want `null` as your argument or parameter list. Instead you can do

```
Method method = classLoader.loadClass("testClass").getMethod("getInstance", new Class[0]);
Object object = method.invoke(null, new Object[0]);
```

or the following as they are varargs methods.

```
Method method = classLoader.loadClass("testClass").getMethod("getInstance");
Object object = method.invoke(null);
// or works but is perhaps confusing.
Object object = method.invoke(null, null);
```

Comment: `method.invoke(null,  null)` works for me

Comment: It is possible its ignored for invoke. I wouldn't include it as it is confusing (it looks like it does something)

Comment: Confusing or not, it is not the error. For backwards compatibility, varargs is the last thing it tries when resolving a method, null can resolve to Object[], and null is a valid value of args.

Comment: This answers has been downvoted, and has a comment stating it's not the error. But it's been accepted. @Austin, how did this answer help you solving your problem?

Comment: @J.A.I.L. The answer fixed the problem. The reason for the downvotes was that it suggested two changes when only the first one was required.  The second change is preferable IMHO, but optional.

Answer (score 1):

For me the following two pieces of code both work correctly for static method and print out the returned value.

```
Method method = myClass.getMethod("getInstance", null);
Object object = method.invoke(null);
System.out.println("returned value: "+object);
```

as well as

```
Method method = myClass.getMethod("getInstance", null);
Object object = method.invoke(null,null);
System.out.println("returned value: "+object);
```

I think that it depend on which Java version you are using (no varargs before 1.5). I'm using Java runtime v1.6.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the problem.
[If the underlying method is static, then the specified obj argument is ignored. It may be null.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Therefore it seems that method itself must be null.

Comment: Method is not null, I've done a System.out.println(method == null); and it prints out false

Answer (score 0):

I bet the problem is in your `getInstance` method. Can you debug it or post it.

Comment: But then he would be getting an InvocationTargetException, not a NullPointerException

Comment: Try writing an example. I have written one that throws a NPE and I get a NPE not a InvocationTargetException.

Comment: Just tried it. It wrapped both manually and natively thrown NPE in an InvocationTargetException. Are you sure you are not thinking of Class.newInstance()?

Answer (score -1):

With `getMethod("getInstance", null)` you are saying "get a method with name 'getInstance' and no parameters".

When you type `method.invoke(null, null)` you are saying "invoke this method on object 'null', **and pass 'null' as the first parameter**".

You should remove that last `null` and just type:

```
Object object = method.invoke(null);
```

Comment: `method.invoke(null,  null)` works for me