# Accessing a static method in java

Tags: java, interface, static

I am coding through interfaces and i need to access a static method defined in the implementation of interface.

At the java class where i am coding, i have access to the interface class and not the actual  implementation class.

I need to access a static method defined in the actual implementation class.

How would i even access it? I dont want to have duplicate logic by creating this static method again at the java class that i want.

Hope the question is clear now

Comment: `Class.staticMethodName();`

Comment: I guess i should have specified , the interface is what i have access to . I do not have access to the implementation class.

Comment: i mean , the interface and the impl class are in different projects.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question clearly?

Comment: Is the question more clear now?

Comment: Yes. If you don't have access the runtime type then the only way to do this is to use reflection. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4770425/18157 - That question asks about `private static` methods, but apart from modifying visibility the answer applies to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces can have static methods since Java 8. Syntax is the same as with classes. If it makes sense, you could move your static method from your implementation to your interface.