# Which arguments to add when invoking method

Tags: java, invoke, illegalargumentexception, getmethod

I'm having a problem when invoking a method from another class. This is the code I'm using:

```
Contact[] database=players1();

System.out.println(sortalg[i]);
try {
    Method method = Sorting.class.getMethod("selectionSort", Comparable[].class);
    method.invoke(database);
}
```

This is the method I want to invoke:

```
public static void selectionSort (Comparable[] data)
{
  int min;

  for (int index = 0; index < data.length-1; index++)
  {
     min = index;
     for (int scan = index + 1; scan < data.length; scan++)
        if (data[scan].compareTo(data[min]) < 0)
           min = scan;

     swap(data, min, index);
  }
}
```

And this is the error I get:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

What arguments do I have to add?

Comment: What does your `Contact` class look like?

Comment: Does `Contact` implement `Comparable`?

Comment: The method is `public static` so there's no need to use reflection here. Just call `ClassName.selectionSort(database)`.

Comment: @Tobias Geiselmann
This is what the Contact class looks like

`public class Contact implements Comparable
{
   private String firstName, lastName, phone; public Contact (String first, String last, String telephone)
   {
      firstName = first;
      lastName = last;
      phone = telephone;
   }
`

Comment: @QBrute
I'm trying to call a method from a string input, so that I can loop through many different methods in one go

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using reflections to call a static method?
Assuming `Contact` implements `Comparable`, why don't you just call

```
Sorting.selectionSort(database);
```

?
If you have to use reflections, you must pass the object to invoke the method on, which is in your case `null`:

```
 method.invoke(null, database);
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770425/how-do-i-invoke-a-private-static-method-using-reflection-java)

Comment: I'd like to use reflections since I'm looping through a large amount of different sorting algorithms. I put the names of all the algorithms in a string array, and from there I figured I'd need to use reflections to call a method from a string.

Adding a null to the invoke unfortunately doesn't help...